# How to check is string valid JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, function

I'm creating a map editor for my game, and I added feature which is adding script to map (textarea), then code writed by person which is editing a map is saved to variable, and then when this person save map, this variable is saved to JSON file as variable in Map object.

When map is loading in the game, this code is transforming into Function object and then it's launching.

My question is: Is there option to check is this string valid JavaScript, and if not `alert("Error" + error)` or something like that?

// Editor is only for developers, not for users, so I don't need to check it on server-side for safety

Comment: [perhaps this would help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: But what will `eval()` return if string will be not correct?

Comment: Just make sure that it is correct. Also avoid using `eval`

Comment: Can you do this on server side or must it be on the client ?

Comment: About the given answers, evaling some arbitrary user input is pretty much the same as you'd hit your head with a hammer. What a splendid opportunity for an attacker. Better to validate the string at the server-side.

Comment: Editor is only for developers, not for users

Comment: @BrunonBlok Well, that makes a difference then. Anyway, thinking about future readers, it might be better, that you'd add that information to the post too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the following :

```
try {
  eval("function f () {"
  + "user code here"
  + "}");
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e+"");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) in a try catch to validate a JS string. This is how it will work. [image]

Invalid JS string will through an uncaught reference error. It would look something like:

```
try {
   eval('console.log("a")');
   console.log('Valid JS');
} catch (e) {
   console.log('Invalid JS');
}
```